# using namespace cv; Xcode doesn't recognize face detection

Tags: iphone, xcode, opencv

I have a problem with OpenCV.
the system doesn't recognize the cv that is called in my .h file.
when I type using namespace cv;
and I command click on cv, it links to the framework.
The other weird thing is my program works in a new file project. It does recognized the cv.
when I add to my existing project, it shows an error for using namespace cv; and cascade classifier, both can't be recognized. thanks!!

Here's

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>
#import <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#import <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

using namespace cv; ----->expected ; after top level declarator

@interface CoolViewController : UIViewController<CvVideoCameraDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView* imageView;

    CvVideoCamera* videoCamera;
    CascadeClassifier faceCascade; ---->unknown type CascadeClassifier did you mean cv::CascadeClassifier
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CvVideoCamera* videoCamera;

- (IBAction)startCamera:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stopCamera:(id)sender;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because xcode cannot recognize  `using namespace` in ObjC code. Make sure you files are `.mm` extension not `.m`

Also please don't put `using namespace` in header file and try to avoid any C++ code in ObjC header file

---

You should to move your ivars to .mm file

```
@implementation CoolViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView* imageView;

    CvVideoCamera* videoCamera;
    CascadeClassifier faceCascade;
}
// your methods
@end
```

Comment: How about the CascadeClassifier, I put the using namespace on my .mm file, but there is still a problem with the CascadeClassifier.